# Building a Binary Tree from Given Data

Tags: tree, integer, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm having trouble understanding how to build a `binary tree` from the given set of numbers...

```
30
15
4
NULL
NULL
20
18
NULL
19
NULL
NULL
NULL
35
32
NULL
NULL
38
NULL
NULL
```

I've gone through my book and notes and can't seem to figure it out. What do the `NULL`'s mean? If you could show me a correct built tree it'd be most helpful, I'm a very visual person. I've changed the value's and `NULL` order from my homework, so don't worry about me not learning from it!

Comment: I think you need to build your tree by floor.
At the end of the first two branches 30 and 15; under 30, there are 4 and NULL and under 15 thera are NULL and 20.You descend one floor:Under 4, there are 18 and NULL (nothing under NULL and NULL)and under 20, there are 19 and NULL etc.NULL seems to mean that there's nothing at the end of a branch.

Comment: That will not be a binary tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only consider the numbers here is how the binary tree should look like:

```
                +--+
                |30|
          +------------------+
          |                  |
       +--+                 ++-+
       |15|                 |35|
  +------------+         +----------+
  |            |       +--+       +--+
+-+          +-++      |32|       |38|
|4|          |20|      +--+       +--+
+-+          +--+
       +-----+
       |18|
       +---+
           |
           +----+
             |19|
             +--+
```

Now, If you go through the list again, you will see that the `NULL` denote when to stop. `30` has a child, `15`, `15` has a child `4`, `4` does not have a child (followed by two `NULL`s), going one up, `15` has a second child `20`, `20` has a children: `18`. `18` does not have left children (denoted by a `NULL` after), but has a right children `19`. It does not have any children (two `NULL`s). `20` also don't have any more children: `NULL` leading to `15`'s other child: `35`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Very probably your question deals with Łukasiewicz codes.

Given a binary tree, a Łukasiewicz code is the sequence generated by the full preorder traversal where the internal nodes are labeled witn `a` and the external ones (the NULL pointers) are labeled with `b`. The use of 'a`/`b` is matter of convention. You could use any other symbols; bits, for instance.

For example, this tree

[image]

which should be the tree corresponding to your problem, has as Łukasiewicz code the following sequence:

> > `aaabbaababbbaabbabb`

Consider drawing the same tree but with the external nodes. Some such as

[image]

In this figure, each external node is drawn with a horizontal bar. Each external node would be a NULL pointer.

Now perform a preorder traversal. When you find an external node (that is a NULL pointer) you print `NULL` and `eol`. When you find a internal node (that is anything different than `NULL`) you print the key value plus `eol`.

You will obtain exactly the sequence that you have provided.

So, the task would be to reconstruct the original tree from this sort of Łukasiewicz traversal. Such task could be accomplished by a routine such as this:

```
Node * to_tree(istream & input)
{
  string val;
  input >> val;
  if (val == "NULL")
    return nullptr;

  Node * p = new Node;
  p->get_key() = atoi(val.c_str());
  p->left  = to_tree(input);
  p->right = to_tree(input);

  return p;
}
```

If the sequence was correctly generated, then you could safely call this function without any risk; it will finish. If you are interested in validate the input, then you could do a preprocessing. You initialize a counter at zero. Each time you find a key you add 1 and when you find a `NULL` you subtract 1. A correct sequence must result at the end in -1. This is thus because all binary tree of `n` nodes has `n + 1` external nodes (or `NULL` pointers). The last visited node is external and this is the only and last time that the counter reaches -1.

You could adapt his routine to you tree implementation and write a program:

```
int main(int, char **)
{
  Node * root = to_tree(cin);
  return 0;
}
```

You compile it and then you execute:

```
./my-program < my-input
```

et voila!

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that the first node indicates the root node of the tree.

The following two nodes in the list are the immediate leaves.

I would presume that the NULL values indicate that the preceding node in the list  has either only one leaf or no leaf nodes.

As for the node ordering in the tree structure, for it to be a binary search tree, each pair of leaf nodes should be either greater or smaller than the parent node, and typically the smaller value should be the left hand leaf node. This means that you can search the tree by starting at the root and choosing the higher or lower leaf node, traversing down the tree until you find the node you want.